# Move from one tab bar to another on click (Tab bar with navigation controllers)

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Hi all I want to segue from first tabbarcontroller to second tabbarcontroller but not able to do so. View Controllers in my TabBar are also embedded with NavigationControllers ,and so when i try to switch tabs it gives me error saying-:

> Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1048d5898) to
>   'abc.CategoriesController' (0x101088d88).

Code I used-:

```
 let barViewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewController
 let svc = barViewControllers![1] as! myController
 svc.myOrder = self.myOrder
```

I tried many solutions but failed to segue can anyone help me? Please explain me concept behind this if anyone can?

`self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1` does work but I can not pass data with this method.

As **Maddy** said-:

Use `let barViewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewController[1] as? myController` to pass data.

But this is the line that gives me above crash

Comment: error suggest on the [1] position of that tabbatcontroller you are getting is UINavigationController you need to find the all stack of that navigationcontroller

Comment: don't cast your [1] to myController cast it to UINavigationController and after what svc.viewControllers gives your all stack viewControllers of navigationcontroller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you got suggest that what you getting from the below code is not the viewController if you

```
let barViewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewController //some what wrong with this
```

best way to access all view controller is as below

```
var svc = self.tabBarController.viewControllers
```

and if you want to access viewControllers by index of them then below one

```
var svc = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as yourVC
```

and last but not in list if you want to access navigation controller from the tabbar

```
var svc = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as UINavigationController
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: that is not giving crash but not even switching tabs and moreover with this last step how will I send data to specific controller.

Comment: you can pass the data using var svc = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as yourVC and for switching the tab you can go with self.tabBarController.selectedIndex and make sure all you chasing up with the viewWillappear of you destination tab